# The set of all bounded elements of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have that $H$ is an inner product space ( . , .) over a subfield $C$ and field $F$ $L_b(H,G)$ is defined to be the set of all bounded elements of $L(H,G)$.

I'm supposed to show that if $S,T \in L_b(H,H)$ Then so is $S \circ T$.

My attempt:

So I think I need to show that $[S(T(\alpha)),S(T(\alpha))] \leq K^2(\alpha,\alpha)$

So I started by letting $\alpha=T(\beta)$.  Then I have $[S(\beta),S(\beta)]$, but I am stuck as to where I go from here.  Anyone have a suggestion?  Thanks!